# How do I know if Java is added to the path in Mac?

Tags: java, macos

I'm reading instructions on setting up a thing and it says,

> Add the Java bin directory to the PATH variable

Now, I don't remember if I've added it to the path before or not but if I open Terminal and type `java -version` from the command line and press enter it shows:

```
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

Does this mean java is already in the path and I don't need to add it? Thanks for all your wonderful support. May your days be filled with flowers and pokemons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see how a command resolves to an executable on your `$PATH`, use the `which` command

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

… or the equivalent bash builtin, `type -p`:

```
$ type -p java
/usr/bin/java
```

On a Mac OS X system with Oracle Java installed, `/usr/bin/java` is a symbolic link.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 23 Oct 16:23 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

Comment: Is that the same as `ls -l \`which java\``?